# What are these dark spots on my picture

Tags: exposure

I took the picture in a hospital room. The spots are not the patients bed. I tried cleaning my lenses. I also took other pictures and this is the only one that has the spots. 
[image]

Comment: I still find it strange since I took many pictures prior to wiping the phone lenses and this is the only one that looks like that. The hospital was filthy I was taking pictures of the condition of the room. I thought it was germs I was seeing, silly huh.

Comment: The spirits of all of the people who have, at one time or another, died in this room?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely whatever was on the lens when you took that photo has since been cleaned off.. it certainly seems like some dirt or something on the lens.

Just one thought, if the phone (assuming it was taken with a mobile pohne camera) had been put down on a page of newspaper that was very slightly wet, the black marks could have been some newspaper print lifting off the paper and sticking to the lens. This is the only thing I can think of so far that may create marks like that

Answer (score -1):

IT would appear that you had dirt on the lens of your camera, when you cleaned the cleans it likely removed the dirt of whatever was on the lens.

When cleaning it's important to be careful as you can scratch the glass with the dirt itself if you're being too rough or do it incorrectly. You should also consider getting microfibre cloths for cleaning similar to glasses, they're good at cleaning - When I do it I try to use the water vapour in my breath on the glass and clean with the microfibre cloth, if it's a phone camera it's not such a big issue but cleaning like that isn't a bad option.